# Writing up the solution for a nonhomogeneous differential equations system with complex Eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The nonhomogeneous linear system of differential equations is given as:

$$ x'(t)=Ax(t)+b $$

It has the following Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors:

$$ \lambda=-1+i, \sqrt{2}, -1-i $$

$$ v_1 = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -i \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}, \qquad
v_2=
 \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix},\qquad v_3=
 \begin{bmatrix}
        i \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

A particular solution is:

$$ x_p(t)=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\
        \sqrt{2} \\
        -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
 $$

How do I find the general real solution for this system? I got:

$$ x(t)=c_1Re\left(\begin{bmatrix}
        -i \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}e^{-t}(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))\right)+c_2\begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}e^{\sqrt{2}t}+c_3 Re\left(\begin{bmatrix}
        i \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}e^{-t}(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))\right)+\begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\
        \sqrt{2} \\
        -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} $$

But the answer is to take the imaginary part of the last term. I don't see how that makes sense.

Comment: If you take the real part of both functions, you get the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix, and $\vec v$ is an eigenvector for that function, then $e^{\lambda t}\vec v$ is a solution to the system of differential equations. In your case, you get $\pmatrix{-i\cr 0\cr 1\cr}\cdot e^{(-1+i)t}$ and $\pmatrix{i\cr 0\cr 1\cr}\cdot e^{(-1-i)t}$.

These solutions have complex number in them; you want to find two new functions which are real-valued, and which span the same subspace (in the linear algebra sense). These two new functions are the real and imaginary parts of either of these solutions. (They are complex conjugates of each other, which also explains why you can't take the real part of both solutions: The real part of $f(t)+g(t)\,i$ equals the real part of $f(t)-g(t)\,i$, so you don't get as many solutions.)